# How to find static files using regex in django in view?

Tags: django, django-views, django-staticfiles

I have django project that has a staticfile with the structure

staticfiles/bundles/static/js/main.[hash of 8 random characters].js

I want to get the name of main.[hash].js in my view. Though I can use python glob to find such file but is there any clean way that is specific to django that I can use to find such file.

Maybe using regex with django.contrib.staticfiles.finders ?